Gazebo Classic: odom plugin not moving "floating in air" bot
I have been "lifting" ROS 2 Humble turtlebot3_gazebo code to make a Gazebo classic sim for my GoPiGo3 robot. (The turtlebot3_gazebo launch works fully correct, but my robot does not move in response to cmd_vel.
My bot appears in Gazebo and I have confirmed the following ROS 2 topics are being published:

ros2 topic echo --once /cmd_vel

ubuntu@DAVEDESK:~/gopi5go_desk/simws$ ros2 topic echo --once /cmd_vel
linear:
  x: 0.26
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0

Launching gazebo with my model/urdf does not declare any errors (the svga_surface_destroy also appears with turtlebot3_gazebo launch):
ubuntu@DAVEDESK:~/gopi5go_desk/simws$ ros2 launch gpg3_gazebo gpg3_world.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ubuntu/gopi5go_desk/roslogs/2024-09-30-00-20-03-394539-DAVEDESK-70597
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
urdf_file_name : gpg3_gopi5go_dave.urdf
urdf_file_name : gpg3_gopi5go_dave.urdf
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [70598]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [70600]
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-3]: process started with pid [70602]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [70604]
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758043781] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_footprint
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758210566] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758224898] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_scan
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758230935] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment dave_eyes_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758236528] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment gopi5go_dave_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758242099] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment imu_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758247573] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment oak_d_w_frame
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758253059] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_left_link
[robot_state_publisher-3] [INFO] [1727670004.758258309] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment wheel_right_link
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670005.143557247] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670005.143909512] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/ubuntu/gopi5go_desk/simws/install/gpg3_gazebo/share/gpg3_gazebo/models/gpg3_gopi5go_dave/model.sdf
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670005.144770080] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670005.145153877] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670005.899812910] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1727670006.410433552] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [gopi5go_dave]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has finished cleanly [pid 70604]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.735049165] [gpg3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 separation set to [0.105090m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.735815841] [gpg3_diff_drive]: Wheel pair 1 diameter set to [0.066050m]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.737240071] [gpg3_diff_drive]: Subscribed to [/cmd_vel]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.739835448] [gpg3_diff_drive]: Advertise odometry on [/odom]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.743073359] [gpg3_diff_drive]: Publishing odom transforms between [odom] and [base_footprint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.756597670] [gpg3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_left_joint]
[gzserver-1] [INFO] [1727670006.756657632] [gpg3_joint_state]: Going to publish joint [wheel_right_joint]
[gzclient-2] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy
[gzclient-2] context mismatch in svga_surface_destroy



ros2 topic echo /joint_states shows wheels rolling:

ubuntu@DAVEDESK:~/gopi5go_desk/simws$ ros2 topic echo --once /joint_states
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 23
    nanosec: 394000000
  frame_id: ''
name:
- wheel_left_joint
- wheel_right_joint
position:
- 62.494270696183875
- 62.49431182145622
velocity:
- 7.870500712400571
- 7.870506090368223
effort: []


And the /odom topic is being published, but the bot is not moving:
ubuntu@DAVEDESK:~/gopi5go_desk/simws$ ros2 topic echo --once /odom
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 125
    nanosec: 904000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_footprint
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: -1.9733522200179194
      y: -0.4985119050889916
      z: 0.18499952985420362
    orientation:
      x: 2.2675750981486369e-07
      y: -2.4142414740205672e-06
      z: 0.0023400580969583284
      w: 0.9999972620573633
...
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.0002125145797608712
      y: -8.627227005519597e-05
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0001484100840613911
...

When I look at the bot visually in Gazebo, it appears it is floating in space, with the wheels not touching the ground.  It seems like I need to adjust one or more z values in the model to get the wheels on the ground.
Is that why it is not moving?  (I hope to get this solved before Classic goes EOL in three months...)


Yes! The pose z value for my base_collision and base_inertia "box z=0.37" was 0, so the collision box was preventing movement.
I changed the z value to 0.19 to put both boxes 5 mm off the floor, and now the bot responds correctly to /cmd_vel topics.
